# Why Cloudfront returning 403 with Guzzle?

Tags: php, amazon-cloudfront, guzzle

I'm consuming a API that uses the CloudFront service,

And I'm getting a 403 error for the requests with Guzzle, but if uses for example PHP Curl or call via Postman or Browser works.

Here a log of the Guzzle:
[Log of guzzle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlRcm.jpg)

And here part of code:

```
/**
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => env('API_HOST'),
        'headers'  => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ],
        'timeout' => 30,
        'debug' => true,
    ]);
}

/**
 * @param string $method
 * @param string $url
 * @param array $body
 * @param bool $isMultipart
 *
 * @return ResponseInterface
 */
private function request(string $method, string $url, array $body = [], bool $isMultipart = false): ResponseInterface
{
    if ($isMultipart) {
        $params['multipart'] = [$body];
    } else {
        $params['json'] = $body;
    }

    $url = $this->appedAuthTokensToUrl($url);

    return $this->client->request($method, $url, $params);
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please post code/logs as text using code blocks? See this for more info https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Ok, so I added the code as text, but the stackoverflow do not let me post with a lot of code

Comment: maybe try trimming it to the relevant portion, or at least in pastebin or something that's easily searchable rather than an image.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found solution. If had a body in the GET request the Cloudfront will return 403.

So in my case the problem is this if (always setting a body):

```php
       if ($isMultipart) {
            $params['multipart'] = [$body];
        } else {
            $params['json'] = $body;
        }
```

[Here link of Cloudfront docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html)